# Jenkins : Unable to access jenkins in local machine

Tags: jenkins, networking, proxy, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to create a Test automation Pipeline to run my selenium scripts, I installed Jenkins in **windows Remote Server 2012**. Used following cmd($ java -jar jenkins.war) to start jenkins. It is working fine in Remote server with url:http://localhost:8080/

But when I'm trying to access it outside Remote server(my local machine) it is not working. am getting  error message "This site can’t be reached"

My local laptop and Remote server is under the same proxy org network.

Can someone help how to resolve this issue , so that other folks can access it and run jobs when required from their laptops

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

- Access Windows Firewall.
- Add an inbound rule to allow port 8080 and
  try accessing the url from any machine in the network.

you could allow/restrict access to all IPs, range of IPs or allow all. But to nullify the issue and confirm if its an issue with whitelisting IPs, I'd first allow access from all IPs with the wildcard *

for Debugging if its a port whitelisting issue, you could also telnet from the machine that you are trying to access this machine -

try

> telnet remote machines IP Port

note: do not use a colon for port input just use a space

Comment: Thanks Satish, Your response helped

Comment: @BhavanKumar - Happy, that helped :)